# How to fix error loading local JSON fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I already asked this question here, but did not receive an answer to it, this time I transferred everything to the sandbox, so that it is easier to understand the essence of the problem

How to get local JSON (fetch)?
I do a service, then I call the class instance
This is not how it works:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const onFetch = async () => {
    const req = await fetch("./data.json");
    return req.json();
  };

  const onMap = () => {
    onFetch().then(data => console.log(data));
  };

  return <div className="App">{onMap()}</div>;
}
```

**Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-montalcini-2z146

Comment: You have to put the URL to an actual JSON file and not a file where the first character is `<` (which is presumably an HTML document).

Comment: Where is the json, show us the structure.

Comment: You can see that `view-source:https://2z146.csb.app/data.json` is the HTML document that bootstraps your react app.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning your code above even if you get your `json` will not work anyway..  `onFetch` is async, and it will remain async even if you place inside a function called `onMap()`..

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/GnFmJva.png?1